# Foreach loop does not work correctly (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

here is my code

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accommodation_vacancies WHERE accommodation_id = '$accom'");
$results = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if($query === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); 
} else {
    print_r($results);
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        echo $result['start_date']; echo "<br/>";
    }           
}
```

And here is my output

[image]

By using the `print_r` commant i can see that The variable `$results` works properly,the query works properly also, i guess that i have mistakes on the foreach loop. 
Thank you.

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are only fetching a single result. Use a while loop instead.

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
```

Side note: As stated in the comments, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. You should NOT learn how to use mysql using these deprecated methods. They will be removed from PHP in some future version and your code will stop working then. If you learn it, use `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: yes but for another occasion the results might be greater than one.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many results there are. The way you do it you only fetch one. The rest is discarded. The common way to fetch all results is a while loop.

Comment: If this answer helped you out, please mark it as a valid answer on the left side directly under the vote-down-button :)